# How do I expire a view cached fragment from console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, actionview

Something like

```
Rails.cache.delete('site_search_form')
```

doesn't seem to work. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: What version of Rails are you running? The cache delete method was added in 2.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cache fragment entries are created with a slightly different key than what you access with Rails.cache.

Use `expire_fragment` instead (you can send it to a controller): [http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Fragments.html#M000438](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActionController/Caching/Fragments.html#method-i-expire_fragment)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If this doesn't work for you too try `Rails.cache.delete_matched 'views/site_search_form*'`

Comment: As of Rails 3, fragment caches have a hash at the end, which is based on the contents of the view in which they are generated. This is so the cache is automatically busted if the view changes, but it makes it difficult to expire by key. You can tell Rails not to add the hash with `skip_digest: true` in the cache call. More info: https://www.reinteractive.net/posts/197-if-you-explicitly-expire-cached-fragments-opt-out-of-cache-digests

Answer (score 55):

ActionController::Base.new.expire_fragment(key)

Comment: ruby-1.8.7-p334 :007 > ActionController::Base.new.expire_fragment(:controller => 'main', :action => 'index')
NoMethodError: undefined method `host_with_port' for nil:NilClass

Comment: As of Rails 3, fragment caches have a hash at the end, which is based on the contents of the view in which they are generated. This is so the cache is automatically busted if the view changes, but it makes it difficult to expire by key. You can tell Rails not to add the hash with `skip_digest: true` in the cache call. More info: https://www.reinteractive.net/posts/197-if-you-explicitly-expire-cached-fragments-opt-out-of-cache-digests

Answer (score 2):

```
Rails.cache.delete "views/site_search_form"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 5 I took the following steps to bust the cache without resorting to `skip_digest: true`. Our problem was that changing the value of I18n strings does not reflect in the computed cache digest so the cache would not get busted automatically.

Here is the view where the cache block is defined:

```
/ views/layouts/_footer.html.slim
- cache :footer do
  span= t('shared.footer')
```

Then in rails console I run:

```
fragment = ActionController::Base.new.view_context.cache_fragment_name(:footer, virtual_path: 'layouts/_footer.html.slim')
ActionController::Base.new.expire_fragment(fragment)
```

`cache_fragment_name` will figure out the digest based on the `virtual_path` keyword argument.

Comment: This is now outdated. `virtual_path` is not a valid option in rails 6.1+.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if you are using Redis as your cache store, is to search and delete from redis directly using the `keys` method.

```
# get direct Redis client from Rails cache store
redis = Rails.cache.redis

# search for your key
keys = redis.keys.grep(/site_search_form/)

# delete the keys
keys.each do |key|
  redis.del(key)
end
```